# HTTP error codes, causing IOException - how to access the response?

Tags: java, http

I have a POST request, made by the client - it could look something like this:

```
https://www.pollmc.com/api/v1/poll.php
PARAMS
    question = Question
    answers = ["Yes","No"]
    oip = true
    secret = false
    displayname = Chris
```

And I'm doing a test, I have banned myself (returning a 403 error). However, when it does return the error, java causes an IOException error (in my try & catch). How can I stop it causing an error, or get the response so I can send it to the client telling them what they did wrong.

Here is my code

```
try {
        urlParams = URLEncoder.encode(urlParams, "UTF-8");

        URL urlObject = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",  String.valueOf(urlParams.length()));
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"); 

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(urlParams.getBytes());

        StringBuilder responseSB = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            responseSB.append(line);

        br.close();
        os.close();

        this.response = responseSB.toString();
        this.responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: start by finding out which line causes the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if the request is a success before reading the response, the logic is the following:

```
if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 200 && connection.getResponseCode() < 400)
    // then read connection.getInputStream()
else
    // then read connection.getErrorStream()
```

Comment: Thankyou! I tried all sorts of things, but your's instantly worked ;) Love ya (no homo)